# Accessing a field in a json string with round brackets

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, object

I am performing **mysql** queries from a **node.js** server and am getting `JSONs` as the result of a query. When `stringified` they show fields that have round brackets in their name.

Here is an example: `[{"COUNT(*)":8}]`. How do I access this field?

My code wont even run if I include the brackets and I get undefined if I don't use them.

Any help on how to access this field would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Because brackets aren't valid property names IIRC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access that value using array notation instead:

```js
let o = [{"COUNT(*)":8}];
console.log(o[0]['COUNT(*)']);
```

If you can edit the query, you could make things simpler by adding a column alias to it:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count ...
```

Then your data would look like this instead:

```
[{count:8}]
```

Comment: If they are able to modify the query themselves this is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

We say we are accessing the first array **[0]** then access the `['COUNT(*)']` value. It's achieved through using a different notation.

```js
let data = [{"COUNT(*)":8}];
console.log(data[0]["COUNT(*)"]);

// Or re-format it, but you did need to learn to access it.
let new_data = {'count': data[0]['COUNT(*)']};
console.log(new_data);
console.log(new_data.count)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = [{"COUNT(*)":8}];
var keys = Object.keys(array);

// from the above we can get all the array element object keys. Since here used single object I have used below length - 1. We can make a loop if has many.

var key_values = array[keys[keys.length - 1]];

// The first object key has got now the first object key value if needed.

var object_keys = Object.keys(key_values);
```